# fetching data from sql database through html code

Tags: sql, tomcat8

I want to receive my data in drop down box, but this code does not seem to be working

```
if(rs.next())
{
    out.print("<select><option>out.print(rs.getString(1))</option></select>");          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it be:

```
if(rs.next())
{
    out.print("<select><option>" + rs.getString(1) + "</option></select>");   
}
```